# Solving coupled PDE with python

Tags: python-3.x, physics, numerical-methods, pde

I do not understand how to solve for the eta and V in my coupled PDE equations using python or a python ode solver. (Or is it possible to do a numerical solution for these couple equations without a solver?)
 I have spent several days on this but I still cannot understand how to start!  Any hints would be helpful .  I understand the example given in

[Solve 4 coupled differential equations in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220940/solve-4-coupled-differential-equations-in-matlab)

but I still need more hints to figure out how to apply these principles to my coupled PDEs below.

[image: coupled PDEs]

I would like to plot a timeseries of eta and V, given forcing inputs of varying timeseries of tau.

x is a point in space, and t is a point in time.  h and f are assigned based on their value of x.
V = V(x,t)   eta = eta(x,t)  tau = tau(x,t)  h = h(x), f = f(x)   while g and rho are constants.  The boundary values are V(0,0) = 0, eta(0,0)=0 , and tau(0,0) = 0. Assuming steady state conditions, the solution (V) is found by equating tau_sy and tau_by.

Comment: Can you clarify which functions depend on what variables, which are constants and for this to work I think you need boundary values, i.e. how eta changes with time at one specific point in space and how V changes in space at one particular moment of time. I am asking if: V = V(x, t),  eta = eta(x, t), tau = tau(x, t) (what are the subscripts?), h = h(x, t), while g, rho and f are constants.

Comment: Thanks, I have now edited the question so that it includes this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here is a somewhat simple numerical scheme, that shows conceptual properties of your system. It is analogous to (explicit) Euler's method. It can be easily generalized to an analogous implicit Euler-like method.

You are given:

The functions `h(x)`, `f(x)` , `tau_sx(x, t)`, `tau_sy(x, t)` and `tau_by(x, t)`

The constants `g` and `rho`

You are looking for :

The functions `V(x, t)` and `eta(x, t)` that satisfy the pair of differential equations above.

To be able to find solutions to this problem, you need to be given:

`V(x, 0) = V0(x)` and `eta(0, t) = eta0(t)`

Assume your domain is `[0, L] X [0, T]`, where `x` in `[0, L]` and `t` in `[0, T]`. Discretize the domain as follows: choose `M` and `N` positive integers and let `dx = L / M` and `dt = T / N`. Then consider only the finite set of points `x = m dx` and `t = n dt` for any integers `m = 0, 1, ..., M` and `n = 0, 1, ..., N`.

I am going to restrict all functions on the finite set of points defined above and use the following notation for an arbitrary function `funct`:

`funct(x, t) = funct[m, n]` and `funct(x) = funct[m]` for any  `x = m dx` and `t = n dt`.

Then, the system of differential equations can be discretized as

`g*(h[m] + eta[m,n])*(eta[m+1, n] - eta[m,n])/dx = f[m]*(h[m] + eta[m,n])*V[m,n] + tau_sx[m,n]/rho`

`(V[m, n+1] - V[m,n])/dt = (tau_sy[m,n] - tau_by[m,n])/(rho*(h[m] + eta[m,n]))`

Solve for `eta[m+1,n]` and `V[m,n+1]`

`eta[m+1,n] = eta[m,n] + f[m]*V[m,n]*dx/g + tau_sx[m,n]*dx/(g*rho*(h[m] + eta[m,n]))`

`V[m,n+1] = V[m,n] + (tau_sy[m,n] - tau_by[m,n])*dt/(rho*(h[m] + eta[m,n]))`

For simplicity, I am going to abbreviate the right hand sides of the equations above as

`eta[m+1,n] = F_eta(m, n, eta[m,n], V[m,n])`

`V[m,n+1] = F_V(m, n, eta[m,n], V[m,n])`

that is, something like

```py
def F_eta(m, n, eta[m,n], V[m,n]):
    return eta[m,n] + f[m]*V[m,n]*dx/g + tau_sx[m,n]*dx/(g*rho*(h[m] + eta[m,n]))

def F_V(m, n,  eta[m,n], V[m,n]):
    return V[m,n] + (tau_sy[m,n] - tau_by[m,n])*dt/(rho*(h[m] + eta[m,n]))
```

From the boundary conditions, we know

`eta[0,n] = eta0[n] = eta0(n*dt)` and

`V[m,0] = V0[m] = V0(m*dx)`

as input, for `m = 0,..., M` and `n = 0,..., N`.

```
for n in range(N):
    for m in range(M):
        eta[m+1,n] = F_eta(m, n, eta[m,n], V[m,n])
        V[m,n+1] = F_V(m, n, eta[m,n], V[m,n])
```

(you have to tweak these loops to reach the rightmost and the upper boundary points, but the philosophy stays the same)

Basically, you follow the pattern: generate the etas along the horizontal x axis and at the same time you generate a V one layer up. Then you move up to the next horizontal level.

```
o --eta--> o --eta--> o --eta--> o --eta--> o
|          |          |          |          | 
V          V          V          V          V
|          |          |          |          |
o --eta--> o --eta--> o --eta--> o --eta--> o
```